# After new windows 10 update 1803 doesn't wont to send (HttpWebRequest,SecurityProtocolType.Tls12)

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, protocols, user-agent, tls1.2

After new windows 10 update (1803) I have problem with sending data. 
MESSAGE:

> the underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occurred on a send

If anyone has any idea I would be very grateful

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Clear();
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
request.Timeout = 10000; //1 sec = 1000 ms

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

byte[] byteStream = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(potpisaniRacunString);

request.ContentLength = byteStream.LongLength;
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

using (Stream writer = request.GetRequestStream()) <---  BOOOM ! (The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.)
{
writer.Write(byteStream, 0, (int)request.ContentLength);
writer.Flush();
}
```

Comment: First, why are you writing all this instead of using an HttpClient.PostAsync? Second, what is the *full* exception, returned by `Exception.ToString()`? 1803 finally removed SMBv1 (good ridance) something announced almost 3 years ago. This caused programs stored on unpatched Linux shares or Win 2003 file servers to fail. It's more likely there's a  problem in the overcomplicated code though. For example, the content type does *not* contain the encoding. A string is encoded in an unusual encoding instead of the expected UTF8

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is resolved. I just needed to build the project on the net framework 4.6 and this has solved all of my problems. :D